# Setting width and height of button to fullfit parent in custom user control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I made custom user control, and i want to place button in that control, with the width same as parent , so that should look like that 
[image]

I can do that in design mode, simply drag and it looks nice, but i need to do that in code .

This is userControl code in designer.cs

```
 this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "ListBoxWithButton";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(339, 362);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

And this is button code

```
   this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = this.Size;
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

With the mark on this line

```
 this.button1.Size = this.Size;
```

when i type that, i get this:

[image]

Why?

Comment: use [`Dock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx) property of control to Fill it in parent control. and if you don't want it to be at specifi place (Top, bottom, Fill etc), you can use [`Anchor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx) property too.

Comment: Do not modify the code in the designer.cs ! - The system relies on it containg the results of your interaction with the designer, not the other way round!!  -  What you want is either Dock.Top  or Anchor.Left+Right+Top

Comment: @Taw  but why, i know what about Dock and Anchor properties , but im wondering why it isnt working in way i explained . Why it make button only half of width of its parent?

Comment: Where is that line located and how got it there? In the degisner.cs of the uc? you wrote it? It doesn't work because you shouldn't do that!

Answer (score 0):

there is [`Anchor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx) property for every control in winform.

this property takes care to resize control properly with resizing it's parent control.

as I can see you want your button's width to be reset with resizing of form, you can Anchor your button to `Left` and `Right`.

**But make sure you are setting this property from [Property window](https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC575342.jpeg&imgrefurl=https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165736.aspx&h=439&w=466&tbnid=duPNyjAm5TBvPM:&q=property%20window%20in%20visual%20studio&tbnh=160&tbnw=169&usg=__obUYMnInni1bVGcmxhqAJCsr3eE%3D&vet=10ahUKEwiwv4DGiNjbAhWDbisKHefWC5UQ9QEILDAA..i&docid=ilEDEM_etqnxNM&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwv4DGiNjbAhWDbisKHefWC5UQ9QEILDAA) and not from designer.cs file.**

Once you do that, in your designer.cs file you can see code like below

```
this.button1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left| AnchorStyles.Right);
```

*this will adjust button from left and right only, if you want it to be adjusted from Top or Button, you should add that too.*

But if you want your button to be docked at specific spot on form o**r to be Filled in parent form**, you should consider [`Dock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx) property too. this property too can be edited from property tab.

it would look like this (in designer.cs)

```
this.button1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```